# Frequency counts of unique values in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I need to count the frequencies of unique values in a numpy matrix so first i used my own method as below:

```
mat = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4],..])
dic = {}
for i in mat:
   for j in i:
      if j in dic:
         dic[j] += 1
      else:
         dic[j] = 0
```

But this approach is expensive for higher order matrix, example 1000X1000 in terms of time, so to reduce the time i tried to use [numpy.bincount](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) but i got ValueError .
Is there any better way of getting the frequency counts of values in a matrix?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get a `ValueError if the input is not 1-dimensional, or contains elements with negative values, or if minlength is non-positive` (from the site). Make sure your array is fine.

Comment: input is not 1-dimensional

Comment: Again `ValueError if the input is not 1-dimensional`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all values in the matrix are non-negative, you can convert the matrix to a numpy array and then use the `bincount`:

```
np.bincount(np.array(mat).reshape(1,mat.size)[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the matrix `mat`

```
mat = np.matrix(np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 20)))
print(mat)

[[6 3 5 8 8 2 5 0 7 8 0 0 1 8 7 7 5 6 2 3]
 [0 1 8 0 2 3 6 8 8 5 8 7 3 0 5 1 5 3 8 3]
 [3 8 0 3 5 5 8 1 9 1 0 7 9 4 6 1 8 8 1 8]
 [7 1 3 0 9 1 8 7 0 5 6 7 4 4 8 2 5 8 0 7]
 [9 7 8 4 1 7 3 8 6 1 2 1 6 4 1 2 5 5 9 1]
 [1 2 3 9 4 6 6 6 2 9 9 3 4 3 7 3 0 3 9 4]
 [9 4 0 1 2 7 1 4 2 3 4 1 3 8 4 7 7 2 3 5]
 [4 5 7 0 9 3 9 7 4 2 8 6 1 2 0 7 3 5 9 7]
 [2 0 7 6 3 3 0 0 2 9 1 3 5 8 4 9 1 9 1 1]
 [5 9 9 0 0 9 1 9 6 0 1 7 0 6 7 3 1 2 4 6]
 [0 1 6 8 6 8 6 3 2 9 6 1 2 7 8 4 9 7 2 9]
 [1 4 4 3 6 6 5 9 1 1 1 3 0 4 3 8 0 8 3 4]
 [9 1 5 9 0 6 6 1 6 9 4 8 9 0 6 1 9 6 8 3]
 [3 9 8 1 2 3 3 5 0 1 1 1 0 6 8 9 5 7 4 2]
 [5 5 5 4 6 4 6 0 6 3 5 5 3 4 0 6 8 6 3 6]
 [5 4 9 5 5 6 8 7 0 3 7 2 2 6 0 4 2 8 4 7]
 [5 8 6 3 6 4 8 5 7 6 6 2 3 6 6 8 5 5 4 0]
 [7 0 8 0 2 0 1 9 2 0 9 9 3 0 7 8 4 4 6 4]
 [8 6 0 9 3 1 3 2 5 6 9 1 9 1 3 2 9 1 1 2]
 [9 4 0 6 2 0 4 0 9 7 4 8 7 2 1 5 3 5 3 2]]
```

You can convert `mat` to a numpy array and use [**`np.unique`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) where you can use the `return_counts=True` parameter to get an array of counts for the corresponding unique values

```
u, c = np.unique(np.array(mat), return_counts=True)
```

`u` has the unique values, and `c` has the counts

```
print(np.stack([u, c]).T)

[[ 0 43]
 [ 1 46]
 [ 2 33]
 [ 3 45]
 [ 4 37]
 [ 5 36]
 [ 6 45]
 [ 7 33]
 [ 8 41]
 [ 9 41]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you get `ValueError: object too deep for desired array` for np.bincount? It can't deal with arrays of more than 1 dimension ("Parameters: x : array_like, 1 dimension, nonnegative ints")

Try `np.bincount(mat.flatten())`

Comment: May be, you can make your answer more formal?